# Radio button and search text box in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have my input form:

```
<form style="font-size: 10pt;  font-family: 'Courier New'; color:black;font-weight:600;margin-left:15px;line-height:25px" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" id="a" name="search" value="EntryId" checked>EntryId <font color="blue">(get Vocab information)</font>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="b" name="search" value="EntryId1">EntryId <font color="blue">(get disease name, protein name)</font>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="c" name="search" value="UniprotId">UniprotId <font color="blue">(get Gene name, Dna Seq)</font>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="d" name="search" value="Genename">Genename <font color="blue">(get Gene information)</font>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="e" name="search" value="EntryId3">EntryId <font color="blue">(get HTML, PubMed information)</font>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <input style="height:30px; width: 300px; border:black 1px solid" type="text" name="Search" >

    <input style="height:30px" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

In this form I am using six radio buttons and each one is representing a stored procedure which is stored in MySQL. If I select a radio button and enter a value in text box (which will be the parameter for my selected procedure) I want output for that procedure.

PHP code:

```
<?php 
$id='';
$query='';

if (isset($_POST['Search']))
{
    $id=$_POST['Search'];
}
echo "<table>";

//connect to database
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mohammad_prostatecancer");

//run the store proc

if (isset($_POST['EntryId1']))
{
    $query= "call DiseaseVocab(".'"'.$id.'")';
}
if (isset($_POST['EntryId2']))
{
    $query= "call DiseaseProtein(".'"'.$id.'")';
}
if (isset($_POST['UniprotId']))
{
    $query= "call getGene(".'"'.$id.'")';
}
if (isset($_POST['Genename']))
{
    $query= "call Getname(".'"'.$id.'")';
}
if (isset($_POST['EntryId3']))
{
    $query= "call Getdata(".'"'.$id.'")';
}

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());

//loop the result set

echo "<tbody>";

// point to the beginning of the array
$check = mysqli_data_seek($result, 0); 
?>
<tr>
    <td><b>EntryId</b></td>
    <td><b>Vocabid</b></td>
    <td><b>VocabSourceName</b></td>
</tr>
<?php

while ($rownew = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($rownew as $k => $v)
    {
        echo "<td>".$v."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>"."<br>";
} 
echo "</tbody></table>";

?>
```

I am not getting any result. I get these warnings:

```
 Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query 
 Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given
```

Comment: change your `if (isset($_POST['EntryId1']))` to `if (isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search'] == 'EntryId1')`, and all others similar

Comment: I changed the name and also tried with your code..it is still giving me same warnings..

Comment: Now I am getting the results but when I am loading the page first time it is giving me warning that $query is null.. do you have any solution for that.

Comment: You need to either set a default value for `$query` OR place all that code inside your `if (isset($_POST['Search'])){...}`

Comment: Improved source code formatting for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

You need the connection in the error, do it like this and then you can see the error.

```
mysqli_error($connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

query is empty because you are checking

```
`if (isset($_POST['EntryId1']))` instead of `if (isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search']=='EntryId1')`
               and switch case would be b`enter code here`etter in this scenario.
```

Comment: I am getting the solution now...but still getting the warning that $query is empty..any solution for that